# HttpContext.Current not supporting for Self hosting

Tags: c#, .net, httpcontext, self-hosting

When I am installing my application through IIS the installation is successful and when doing a SelfHosting installation, it fails. When debugging found that HttpContext.Current is always coming as null for Self-hosting and the password is never getting decrypted.

```
if (HttpContext.Current != null)
{
   var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
   if (request.PathInfo.Equals("/api/login"))
   {
    password = Decrypt(password);
   }
}
```

Is there any alternative for HttpContext.Current so that it supports for both IIS and Self hosting installation? Can anyone please hlep!

Note: I tried HttpContextShim and modified my code but still facing the same issue. What more has to be added?

```
using HttpContext = HttpContextShim.HttpContext;
if (HttpContext.Current != null)
{
  password = Decrypt(password);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`HttpContext`is not available in a self-hosted environment. `HttpContext` is set by the ASP.Net pipeline, `HttpContext` is only available in the Web-Hosting mode, in which the HttpControllerHandler creates the request.

`httpcontext-shim` is An abstraction for HttpContext that works in self-hosted ASP.NET Web API.

```
PM> Install-Package HttpContextShim
```

Reference: https://github.com/danielcrenna/vault/tree/master/httpcontext-shim

Comment: While trying to install this it is overwriting all the other existing packages like Newtonsoft.Json and all and causing error in the application. Is there any way for it not to overwrite the existing dlls?

Comment: Using HttpContextShim is still giving HttpContext.Current as null. What more should I add?